# Graph Template Class

Tags: c++, stl

I am working on Graph Template Class. Here is what I written till now.

```
#ifndef __GRAPH_H__
#define __GRAPH_H__

#include <map>
#include <list>

template <typename _Ty>
class Graph {
private:
    template <typename _Ty>
    class Vertex {
    public:
        Vertex(_Ty in) : m_Label(in) {
        }
        ~Vertex() {
        }
    private:
        _Ty m_Label;
    protected:
    };

public:
    typedef Vertex<_Ty>                       VertexType;
    typedef std::list<VertexType>             AdjListType;
    typedef std::map<VertexType,AdjListType>  GraphType;

public:
    Graph(bool bType = false) : m_Type(bType) {
    }
    ~Graph() {
    }
    void AddEdge(VertexType vLevt, VertexType vRight) {
    }
private:
    // true if bidirectional
    // false if unidirectional.
    bool m_Type; 
    GraphType m_Graph;
protected:
};

#endif
```

Here is how I am using this class.

```
#include "Graph.h"
#include <string>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Graph<int> myGraph;
    myGraph.AddEdge(1,2);

    Graph<char *> myGraph2;
    myGraph2.AddEdge("A","B");

    Graph<std::string> myGraph3;
    myGraph3.AddEdge("A","B");

}
```

`myGraph3` is giving me compilation error.
`error C2664: 'Graph<_Ty>::AddEdge' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [2]' to 'Graph<_Ty>::Vertex<_Ty>'`

Why this is error , if `std::string test = "ABC";` works.

Comment: Off topic, but you are using reserved names for your include guards and template parameters; you should remove the leading underscores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string test = "ABC";` does implicit casting, but it is not happening while calling the function. Try `myGraph3.AddEdge(std::string("A"),std::string("B"));`.

Function call overloading by defining another function as in

```
void AddEdge(_Ty vLevt, _Ty vRight) {
        this->AddEdge((VertexType) vLevt, (VertexType) vRight);
    }
```

helps.

The other issue with your code (at least for gcc) is that you are using the same parameter `_Ty` in two nested template declarations. The complete, correct code, that works for me is:

```
#include <map>
#include <list>

template <typename _Ty>
class Graph {
private:
    template <typename _Tyv>
    class Vertex {
    public:
        Vertex(_Tyv in) : m_Label(in) {
        }
        ~Vertex() {
        }
    private:
        _Tyv m_Label;
    protected:
    };

public:
    typedef Vertex<_Ty>                       VertexType;
    typedef std::list<VertexType>             AdjListType;
    typedef std::map<VertexType,AdjListType>  GraphType;

public:
    Graph(bool bType = false) : m_Type(bType) {
    }
    ~Graph() {
    }
    void AddEdge(VertexType vLevt, VertexType vRight) {
    }
    void AddEdge(_Ty vLevt, _Ty vRight) {
        this->AddEdge((VertexType) vLevt, (VertexType) vRight);
    }
private:
    // true if bidirectional
    // false if unidirectional.
    bool m_Type;
    GraphType m_Graph;
protected:
};
```

Comment: Can function call operator overloading help me in this case

Comment: @Avinash: no, but giving `Vertex` a templated constructor would (`template <typename U> Vertex(U const & in) : m_Label(in) {}`). Then `char*` would be convertible to `Vertex<std::string>`, and your code should work as it is.

Comment: @Avinash: that's because your second example is relying on a deprecated conversion from a string literal to a non-const pointer; with my change, that becomes an invalid conversion from a const array to a non-const pointer. You should be using `char const *` there, or using non-const strings as the arguments.

Comment: Avinash, I have given another function to overload AddEdge. Does this work?

Answer (score 1):

That requires two *implicit* conversions

- First `"A"` needs to convert into `std::string`
- Then `std::string` needs to convert into `Vertex<std::string>` (the nested type).

That is chained-implicit-conversion which is not allowed.

But when you write `std::string test = "ABC"`, then only one conversion happens: `char[4]` to `std::string`. That is it.

So the solution is, do one conversion yourself by explicitly passing `std::string`, and let the compiler do the other conversion:

```
 Graph<std::string> myGraph3;
 myGraph3.AddEdge(std::string("A"),std::string("B"));
```

Now only one conversion is needed : `std::string` to `Vertex<std::string>`. Therefore, it will compile.